# Compilation issues in Nest.js when changes made in a service.ts file

Tags: javascript, typescript, nestjs

I am working on a Nest.js project and
this is what I have in the `automobile.service.ts`

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { Car } from './entities/car.entity';
import { Repository } from 'typeorm';

import { CreateAutoDto } from './dto/create-auto.dto';
import { UpdateAutoDto } from './dto/update-auto.dto';


export class AutoService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(Car)
    private autoRepository:Repository<Car>,
  ){}


  create(createAutoDto: CreateAutoDto) {
    return this.autoRepository.save(createAutoDto)
```

The issue I am facing right now is, after I typed `nom run start:dev` in the terminal, the log just stopped from here:

```
[Nest] 234 - 10/10/2021, 7:36:53 PM [NestFactory] Starting Nest application...

[Nest] 234 - 10/10/2021, 7:36:54 PM [InstanceLoader] TypeOrmModule dependencies initialized +958ms
```

Nothing more, and with that I can't open the page in browser. However, if I have the whole

```
constructor(
    @InjectRepository(Car)
    private autoRepository:Repository<Car>,
  ){}
```

thing deleted, the code finishes compiling without any error.

```
[Nest] 101 - 10/10/2021, 7:05:57 PM [NestApplication] Nest application successfully started +3ms
```

I am new to Nest.js. What could be the root-cause here?

EDIT:
In `automobile.module.ts`

```
import { AutoService } from './automobile.service';
import { AutoController } from './automobile.controller';

@Module({
  controllers: [AutoController],
  providers: [AutoService],
})
export class AutoModule {}
```

Comment: db connection issues, maybe

Comment: I think we'd need to have more context as to what's going  on here. If deleting the `@InjectRepostory()` makes it work, it seems like there's an uncaught exception under the hood of Nest's resolution. Can you show your related `automobile.module.ts` file?

Comment: I just added code from ```automobile.module.ts```

Comment: k, i see where the problem is now

Comment: I would say it is most likely to be caused by timeout on the DB connection as mentioned by @MicaelLevi above. It may take long time before it will throw, which makes you think "nothing happens".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what I did wrong was that in `automobile.module.ts` file, I forgot to include `imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([Car])]`, and that might be the root-cause resulting in the timeout on the DB connection.